# filter sanizite user input float numbers comma/dot issue

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering

Trying to figure out how to user filters in php in a sensible way

```
//Do sanization of user input
//$_POST['amount_ecb'] can be 77,7 or 77.7

$amount = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'amount_ecb', 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

if posted value is 77.7 it sets amount correctly, but if user sets number with a comma instead of a dot (eg. 77,7) `$amount` returns 77

I want it to return 77.7 in both cases. Is this possible to solve with filters?

**UPDATE**
After feedback (posted answer) I still have the same issue:

When using

```
$_POST['amount_ecb'] = str_replace(',', '.', $_POST['amount_ecb']);
```

before

This it was it returns

**$_POST object**

```
array (size=5)
  'amount_ecb' => string '77.7' (length=4)
  'from_ecb' => string 'GBP' (length=3)
  'to_ecb' => string 'SEK' (length=3)
  'submit' => string 'Calculate currency' (length=18)
  'result_decimals' => string '4' (length=1)
```

**$amount**

```
string '777' (length=3)
```

Comment: To be on safe side just replace , to .; If user inserted will be replaced; Rest you've done;

Comment: But how would I do that replacement in this case then? The filter_input function doesn't use $_POST directly which makes it impossible to to do something like $amount = str_replace(',','.',$_POST['amount_ecb'];

Comment: Are you using codeigniter?

Comment: No using Wordpress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Finally found how this could be solved!** (even if I think this should be built into the `input_filter` somehow).

If someone stumbles upon the same issue...

```
$amount_ecb = str_replace(',', '.', $_POST['amount_ecb']);
$amount = filter_var($amount_ecb, 
FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
```

I put the posted value into another variable (`$amount_ecb`), replaced the comma with dots and then use `filter_var` on `$amount_ecb` - instead of using `filter_input` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* find , and replace with . if any; */
$_GET['search'] = str_replace(',', '.', $_GET['search']);

/* finally filter data */
$amount = filter_var($_GET['search'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, array(
  'flags'=>FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION));
```

Comment: This looked great in theory, but it does not work I'm afraid. The posted array does of course replace the comma with dot, but the filter_input function does not seem to access the $_POST directly.

Comment: I've solved it :-) Thanks for putting me in right direction!